# Rails 4. Model Predefined values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I'm creating rails API. I have a model with predefined values

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
       create_table :messages do |t|
           t.string :status #set [delivered, pending, error]
       end
   end
end
```

Attribute **status** may have only 3 values `delivered, pending, error`. How can I add validation for field **status** in models

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion

Comment: @liamneesonsarmsauce Thanks! I missed that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your model

```
validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => %w( delivered pending error )
```

More Info **[here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_inclusion_of)**